# Building query and show all users reported the item in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Recently I've started to learn laravel and currently I work with version 5.2. 
What I have is Flag/Report system with which user can Report item for various reasons and the report is saved in database. So far this works great. I want now in backend(admin dashboard) when I select report to see details of it to see also all users who are reported this particular item.

So far I see only one user but I can't figured how to make the model and query.

So my Item model has

```
public function report(){        
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Report');
}
```

Report mode has

```
public function reportedItem(){

    return $this->hasMany('Item','item_id');
}
```

And in controller this

```
public function details( $report_id ){

    $flags = Report::where('report_id', '=', $report_id)->get();

    return view('details', compact('flags'));
 }
```

In table `reports` one item can have many reports from many users. Any help here is appreciated.

**Update** with latest code changes.

Model Report

```
public function reportedItem(){

    $this->hasMany('App\Item', 'id', 'item_id');
}
```

Controller

```
public function details( $item_id ){

    $flags = Item::find($item_id)->reportedItem;      

    return view('details', compact('flags'));
}
```

button

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' => array('details', $flag->item_id), 'method' => 'get')) !!}               
    <button>Details</button>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

in details.blade

```
@foreach($flags as $flag)
   ....
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller change your code from

```
public function details( $report_id ){    
    $flags = Report::where('report_id', '=', $report_id)->get();    
    return view('details', compact('flags'));
 }
```

to

```
public function details( $item_id ){
        $flags = App\Item::find($item_id)->report;   
        return view('details', compact('flags'));
     }
```

After that you can acces each detail like

```
foreach ($flags as $flag) {
    //
}
```

**EDIT**

in your `Report` model change

```
public function reportedItem(){    
   $this->hasMany('App\Item', 'item_id','id');
}
```

to

```
public function reportedItem(){    
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Item');
}
```

and Item model

```
public function report(){        
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Report');
}
```

to

```
public function report(){        
    return $this->('App\Report', 'item_id','id'); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it's looking in items table instead of in reports..`SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'items.item_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from items where items.item_id = 9 and items.item_id is not null)` or I'm missing something here?

Comment: Your relationship in Report model is wrong. I will update my answer. Check [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) for more help.

Comment: Yes, I've tried this. But still trying to query `items` table. Should query `reports` table and if I'm clicked on `reportd_id=1` should query something like `select * from reports where report_id = 1 join items on report.item_id = item.item_id....`

Comment: Have you tried with return `$this->hasMany('App\Item', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');` ?

Comment: Got this error: `Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation`

Comment: Because of `()` at the end... `Report::find($report_id)->reportedItem();` but now I've got `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Comment: `dd($flags)` return null .. but is not null because there are records in database

Comment: use `Report::find($report_id)->reportedItem`, not `Report::find($report_id)->reportedItem()`

Comment: This error again `Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: Please update your question with latest changes of code and how you access objects in your view to help you further

Comment: I'm now trying to query items table based on item id which is clicked and join report table

Comment: I have updated my answer, you changed order of foreign keys i think. Check report model again  `$this->hasMany('App\Item', 'item_id','id');`

Comment: Still same : `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Comment: Change in your controller `$flags = Item::find($item_id)->reportedItem;`  to `$flags = Report::find($item_id)->reportedItem; `

Comment: `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'items.report_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `items` where `items`.`report_id` = 9 and `items`.`report_id` is not null)` it is querying items like this..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133450/discussion-between-kukec-and-jason-paddle).